# Is an $(n-1)$-dimensional submanifold of an $n$-dimensional manifold orientable?

Tags: differential-geometry, submanifold

Is it true that every $(n-1)$-dimensional submanifold of a compact (compact without boundary) $n$-dimensional manifold is orientable ?
I think, that the answer is no, but I can’t provide it with an example. I thought about Möbius strip and Klein bottle. But the dimensions are not corresponding (the difference is 2 , not 1)

Comment: you can try with examples of n-dimensional compact manifolds.. what all compact n dimensional manifolds do you know? Then write down the examples of orientable manifolds and examples of unorientable manifolds...

Comment: $n$-dimensional circle , $n$-dimensional torus , Klein bottle

Comment: take some care in writing the comments. It is all discrete words you have written. try to write it as you would write in an exam... take some care, answer will come easily....

Comment: So orientable manifolds for example are: real projective space if the dimension is odd, tangent bundle is also orientable for every manifold, spheres are orientable. Non-orientable are Möbius strip, real projective space for even dimensions , Klein bottle...this is the list of just possibility of orientation

Comment: So if I take $M\times S^1$ as it was mentioned . I will get  non-orientable compact manifold where $M$ is Möbius strip without boundary for example. Is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take $M$ a non-orientable compact $(n-1)$-manifold, then it is a submanifold of $M\times S^1$ which is compact.

For example you can take $M$ to be the Klein bottle.

Comment: As you have given complete answer, you can also give some examples of non-orientable compact manifold..

Answer (score 0):

All the examples in Adam Chalumeau's answer are non-orientable hypersurfaces of non-orientable manifolds. It is worth noting that there are non-orientable hypersurfaces of orientable manifolds. For example, $\mathbb{RP}^{2n}$ is a hypersurface in $\mathbb{RP}^{2n+1}$; the former is non-orientable while the latter is orientable.